# C# Calling a function?

Tags: c#

Hi i'm getting this error, do I have to add a special namespace? "The type or namespace name 'call' could not be found..."

```
private void start_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    call DoIt();

}

void DoIt() 
{
    ...code
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just invoke `DoIt` directly without `call`.  There is no such operation as `call` in C#

```
DoIt();
```

Answer (score 3):

One doesn't use `call` to invoke a function in C#, so fix your code thus:

```
private void start_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DoIt();
}
```

As @Kheldar has suggested, you're probably thinking of the [call statement in Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sxz296wz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), which isn't a feature of C#.

Answer (score 2):

Remove "call" and your code will run.

VB6 or Windows Script coder much? ;)

Answer (score 1):

Remove `call` in your snippet, in C# does not exist such kind of keyword. `DoIt();` will execute your function pretty well.

Anyway, I think you might want to read something like:

- [MSDN C# Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288436%28VS.71%29.aspx);
- [Best .NET C# Books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477748/what-are-the-best-c-net-books);